# Test if object implements interface

Tags: java

This has probably been asked before, but a quick search only brought up the same question asked for C#. [See here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface)

What I basically want to do is to check wether a given object implements a given interface.

I kind of figured out a solution but this is just not comfortable enough to use it frequently in if or case statements and I was wondering wether Java does not have built-in solution.

```
public static Boolean implementsInterface(Object object, Class interf){
    for (Class c : object.getClass().getInterfaces()) {
        if (c.equals(interf)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

EDIT: Ok, thanks for your answers. Especially to Damien Pollet and Noldorin, you made me rethink my design so I don't test for interfaces anymore.

Comment: Can't you just try casting and catch the exception if one is thrown (or check for a null result even, if Java has anything analagous to the C# "as" operator)? I'm a C# coder rather than a Java one, so I'm mainly just guessing here, though I would think such an approach would be possible in any OO language.

Comment: Throwing exception is good practice in this case only if you don't have to care about performance.

Comment: Pardon me but where are those answers made you re-think your design? Even if they deleted, what were they? Could you please help me @sebastiangeiger

Comment: @ozanmuyes I'm sorry, I haven't written Java in over 4 years and unfortunately I can't remember what I did.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The [`instanceof`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.20.2) operator does the work in a [`NullPointerException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) safe way. For example:

```
 if ("" instanceof java.io.Serializable) {
     // it's true
 }
```

yields true. Since:

```
 if (null instanceof AnyType) {
     // never reached
 }
```

yields false, the `instanceof` operator is null safe (the code you posted isn't).

**instanceof** is the built-in, compile-time safe alternative to [Class#isInstance(Object)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object))

Comment: instanceof only works on class literals though. So it can't be used in the OP's case

Comment: sure, it is compile-time safe; and it is the built-in way and it is the argument of the question (imho)

Comment: @LordOfThePigs no it doesn't. It checks if an interface is implemented aswell.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: you misunderstood my point. Class literals is when you write things like `MyClass.class` or `MyInterface.class` in your source code. Class literals can refer to classes, interfaces and primitive types, and will return a corresponding instance the Class class. My point is the OP is not using a class literal, but an instance of the Class class instead, and unfortunately the right hand side operator of the `instanceof` keyword must be a class literal, not an instance of the Class class.

Comment: @dsdsdsdsd Since this post I didn't even heard/read about it, but after looking up on Google I figured it out it is abbreviation of the Null Pointer Exception.

Answer (score 43):

This should do:

```
public static boolean implementsInterface(Object object, Class interf){
    return interf.isInstance(object);
}
```

For example,

```
 java.io.Serializable.class.isInstance("a test string")
```

evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 9):

I prefer `instanceof`:

```
if (obj instanceof SomeType) { ... }
```

which is much more common and readable than `SomeType.isInstance(obj)`

Comment: Remember that `if (obj instanceof SomeType) { ... }` is static (that is - it cannot change at runtime) and `SomeType.isInstance(obj)` is dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

that was easy :

```
   interf.isInstance(object)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to test for interfaces:

```
public List<myType> getElement(Class<?> clazz) {
    List<myType> els = new ArrayList<myType>();
    for (myType e: this.elements.values()) {
        if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(e.getClass())) {
            els.add(e);
        }
    }
    return els;
```

}

clazz is an Interface and myType is a Type that you defined that may implement a number of interfaces. With this code you get only the types that implement a defined interface

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem tonight with android and after looking at the javadoc solutions I came up with this real working solution just for people like me that need a little more than a javadoc explanation.

Here's a working example with an actual interface using android java.
It checks the activity that called implemented the AboutDialogListener interface
before attempting to cast the AboutDialogListener field.

```
public class About extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener,
    OnCheckedChangeListener {

public static final String FIRST_RUN_ABOUT = "com.gosylvester.bestrides.firstrunabout";


public interface AboutDialogListener {
    void onFinishEditDialog(Boolean _Checked);
}

private AboutDialogListener adl;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Activity a = this.getActivity();
    if (AboutDialogListener.class.isInstance(a)) {
        adl = (AboutDialogListener) a;
        }
}
```

...
Later I check if the field adl is !null before calling the interface

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    sharedPref.edit().putBoolean(About.FIRST_RUN_ABOUT, _Checked).commit();
    // if there is an interface call it.
    if (adl != null) {
        adl.onFinishEditDialog(is_Checked());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Apache commons-lang ArrayUtils, see if the interface you require is contained in the interfaces of you object

```
public static Boolean implementsInterface(Object object, Class interf){
    return ArrayUtils.contains(object.getClass().getInterfaces(), interf);
}
```