# Java - Check if an object (class) implements an interface

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to check if an object implements an interface (If that class of that object implements the interface) in Java.

How do I do that?

I saw you can do this.getClass().getInterfaces(), but that gives me an array, and I need to search that array, but what do I use to check?

Comment: When you were asking your question, just typing in your title, the SO interface showed you a list of existing questions related to it. [The question assylias, myself, and others](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766106/test-if-object-implements-interface) pointed to above was **number two on that list**. Why bother to ask the question again when the answer is already there?

Comment: The question does not deserve being downvoted so much...

Comment: @assylias: Some people interpret "...does not show research effort..." as including not bothering to look at the list of similar questions when they were asking. (For good or ill...)

Comment: I guess OP wants to know that either a class has implement a interface or not.Like if he is using a class A from any API then he wants to know that if A has implemented any interface.
For OP -> you should study the Docs for that purpose

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I know but for a new user it is not necessarily obvious - your comment is more useful than serial downvoting.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to know if instance `foo` is of a class implementing a given interface, you can use `instanceof`:

```
if (foo instanceof TheInterface)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [instanceof](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.2) operator in Java. JLS says,

*At run time, the result of the instanceof operator is true if the value of the RelationalExpression is not null and the reference could be cast to the ReferenceType without raising a ClassCastException.*

`instanceof` operator is a binary operator used to test if an object (instance) is a sub type of a given type.

```
// checks if bar object's class implements SomeInterface
if (bar instanceof SomeInterface)
```