# Possible null assignment in ReSharper. I can't see how that can be null?

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I get following warning:

> Possible 'null' assignment to an entity marked with 'Value cannot be
>   null' attribute

My code:

```
if (verifier.GetType().GetInterface(typeof(IAsyncVerifier).FullName, true) == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
```

Warning given on `typeof(IAsyncVerifier).FullName` part. How that can be null? How would you fix it? Or maybe there is better way to figure if object implements specific interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Test if object implements interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Or maybe there is better way to figure if object implements specific interface?**

Use is operator for to check if an object's type is derived from a particular interface or class

```
if (verifier is IAsyncVerifier)
```

Look at this MSDN article [Type.FullName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.fullname.aspx) It says that property will return nothing.

> ... Nothing if the current instance represents a generic type parameter,
>   an array type, pointer type, or byref type based on a type parameter,
>   or a generic type that is not a generic type definition but contains
>   unresolved type parameters.

If you are sure that when you access FullName this will not be null in any case you can disable this warning using `//resharper disable` comment