# Activator.CreateInstance with two interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, activator

I have a project I am working on that I would like to leverage Activator.createInstance with so that I can dynamically pull class names out of XML. The classes must subscribe to at least one of two interfaces depending on their functionality. My question is, when I use Activator.CreateInstance, what is the best way to tell which interface the class I've instantiated subscribes to? Should I wrap the cast in a try catch? It seems like that would be awful slow. Maybe I should cast it an obj and then call GetType and compare that to my interface names? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "what is the best way to tell which interface the class I've instantiated subscribes to", what does this mean?

Comment: you could also just store that information in the xml with the class name.

Comment: Matthew, Ani's answer below took care of it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am storing it with the class name, but that class could be subscribing to two different interfaces. I could store the interfaces it uses, but that would require the person altering the XML file to have a better understanding of how my code works, something I don't have the luxury of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you've already created the object? Then it's as simple as using as the [`is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(...);
bool objIsIMyInterface = obj is IMyInterface;
```

If you'd like to test at the point you've created a `System.Type`, you can use [`Type.IsAssignableFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
Type type = ...
bool typeIsIMyInterface = typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type);
```

Comment: Yes, I think you hit the nail on the head. Just as I saw your answer I found this which is similar

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface

Thanks for your help!