# Is this a covariance/contravariance issue with my design?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, variance

I am struggling with what I believe is a covariance/contravariance problem with my design. I want return a generic object which is only known at run time.

I have the following classes/interfaces

```
public interface IBaseRepository
{
    int UserId { get; set; }

    // Retrieve
    SyncData GetRetrieveData();

    // Update
    SyncData GetUpdateData();
}

public interface IDomainRepository<T> : IBaseRepository where T : IDomainObject
{
    object GetValue(T domainObject, string id);
    void SetValue(T domainObject, string id, object value);

    // retrieve data 
    BatchResults<T> Retrieve();

    // update data
    BatchResults<T> Update(SynchroniseList synchroniseList);
}
```

I have some implementations of these:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : IBaseRepository
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual SyncData GetRetrieveData()
    {
        return new SyncData();
    }

    public virtual SyncData GetUpdateData()
    {
        return new SyncData();
    }
}

public MyTaskRepository : BaseRepository, IDomainRepository<MyTask>
{
    public object GetValue(MyTask domainObject, string id)
    {
        return domainObject.GetValue();
    }

    void SetValue(MyTask domainObject, string id, object value)
    {
        domainObject.SetValue();
    }

    // retrieve data 
    public BatchResults<MyTask> Retrieve()
    {
        // do stuff specific to MyTask
        return new BatchResults<MyTask>();
    }

    // update data
    BatchResults<T> Update(SynchroniseList synchroniseList)
    {
        // do stuff specific to MyTask
        return new BatchResults<MyTask>();
    }
}

public MyOtherTaskRepository : BaseRepository, IDomainRepository<MyOtherTask>
{
    ...
}
```

The problem I am having is when using this repository. In a form I have

```
IBaseRepository repo = RepositoryFactory.Create(some parameters);
```

This returns a IDomainRepository which allows my to get/set retrieve/update data.

However, I dont know how to call Retrieve/Update as I cant cast to IDomainRepository because I dont know what domain object I will be working with.

I have been reading up on covariance/contravariance as I am thinking it has something to do with that
However, I also have the feeling that my design is wrong in the sense I have made this overly complicated. 
I believe I could implement this in say c# 2.0 so I think I shouldnt event be concerned about covariance/contravariance.

Is it my design or do I need to sort out my in/out interfaces?

Comment: I do not see any usages of either contra or covariance; so why are you asking about it with respect to your code?

Comment: just return `IDomainRepository<T>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the factory to return `IDomainRepository<T>`, as a commenter suggested.  Otherwise use the `as` operator to typecast the interface pointer:

```
IBaseRepository repo = RepositoryFactory.Create(...);
IDomainRepository<MyTask> domainRepo = repo as IDomainRepository<MyTask>;
if (domainRepo != nil)
{
    // domainRepo implements IDomainRepository<MyTask>.
}
```

But testing the object to identify its type doesn't encourage polymorphic behaviour.

See also [Test if object implements interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface).