# How can I tell if my generic type supports a certain interface and convert back and forthto that interface for a function?

Tags: c#, generics, collections, interface

I have a method that looks like this:

```
private IEnumerable<T> QueryCollection<T>() where T : BaseObj
{
      IEnumerable<T> items = query<T>();
      return items;
}
```

I now have a situation where I want to filter this items collection IF the "T" supports a certain interface (it might not so i can't simply add it as a constraint of T). So i want something like this:

```
private IEnumerable<T> QueryCollection<T>() where T : BaseObj
{
     IEnumerable<T> items = query<T>();

     if (typeOf(T).GetInterface(ITeamFilterable) != null)
     {
           items = FilterByTeams(items);
     }
     return items;
}
```

What is the recommended way of checking if my generic Type supports a certain interface **and then if YES, then

1. Use that within the method to filter a collection
2. But still return the collection at type "T" in the overall method

**NOTE:**  FilterByTeams takes in an:

```
   IEnumerable<ITeamFilterable>
```

AND returns

```
   IEnumerable<ITeamFilterable>
```

Do I need to cast the collection 2 times (one to convert to List of the interface  and then again to convert back to list of T?)

Comment: Or just use `is` / `as` + `!= null`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410227/test-if-object-implements-interface

Comment: This is **not a duplicate** since the linked questions don't deal with covariance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't use `is`/`as` in this case unless you can start enumerating the query.

You can use reflection like that:

```
private IEnumerable<T> QueryCollection<T>() where T : BaseObj
{
     IEnumerable<T> items = query<T>();

     if (typeof(ITeamFilterable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
           items = (IEnumerable<T>)(object)FilterByTeams(items.Cast<ITeamFilterable>());

     return items;
}
```

But if you can enumerate the query, you can do that to avoid reflection (assuming you have no `null` items):

```
private IEnumerable<T> QueryCollection<T>() where T : BaseObj
{
     IEnumerable<T> items = query<T>();
     ICollection<T> itemsCollection = items as ICollection<T> ?? items.ToList();

     if (itemsCollection.Count > 0)
     {
         var firstItem = itemsCollection.First();
         if (firstItem is ITeamFilterable)
             return (IEnumerable<T>)(object)FilterByTeams(itemsCollection.Cast<ITeamFilterable>());
     }

     return itemsCollection;
}
```

The casts will work since `ITeamFilterable` is a `T` and `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, but you have to cast to `object` in-between to satisfy the generics constraints. Using these casts, there's no need to copy items around.

Comment: see the update to my question.  Your answer doesn't work because the FilterByTeams doesn't return collection of T but rather collection of the ITeamFilterable interface

Comment: @leora Answer updated, this should work

Comment: so your answer, in short, is Yes, you need to cast back and forth

Comment: In short, yes. But my point is you don't need to create a new list of `ITeamFilterable` just for the sake of having a list of `ITeamFilterable`, a cast is sufficient and does not copy data around. I think I misunderstood this aspect of your question.